# failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c composer install]: exit code: 1

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

Trying to run `composer install` during `docker compose build` from inside the php container, but it errors out at the end acting like the composer.json file isn't there.  However if I comment out the last line in the Dockerfile (ie. RUN composer install), then do something like, `docker exec -it <container name> bash`, manually run `composer install` from inside the container where `/var/www/html/composer.json` does in fact exist it works.

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite

WORKDIR /var/www/html

## install and run composer so that this test is self contained
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN composer install
```

Produces the following

```
 => ERROR [stage-0 8/8] RUN composer install                                                                                                                                                                       0.5s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [stage-0 8/8] RUN composer install:
#0 0.437 Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
#0 0.446 Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
#0 0.446 To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c composer install]: exit code: 1
```

In case it's important this is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: unless-stopped

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./docker/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MARIADB_DATABASE: xxx
      MARIADB_USER: xxx
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: xxx
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: "Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html" -- you don't have an instruction in your Dockerfile to add your project to the image.

Comment: Not sure what that means.  How do I add my project to the image?

Comment: The build step creates the image and executes everything in your Dockerfile. This step has no knowledge of the volumes you’ve defined in your docker-compose file. That is only used when you start your services, after the image has been built. So if you want to run `composer install` during the build phase, you’ll have to copy your application to your image by including `COPY src /var/www/html` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: The problem with that is that as soon as you mount your local folder into your service when you run `docker-compose up`, you overwrite the folder (with the installed dependencies) inside the image with your own local folder, which may not have those dependencies unless you’ve run `composer install` locally. A different option might be to add an entrypoint script to the image that will always run `composer install` on startup.

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear to you? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're already pretty close with your container build directives, it's just that I'd say you only need the composer.json *during* the build and you actually need to have the vendor folder in the service container afterwards.

It's bascially two commands:

First update the build instructions:

```
<<'DOCKERFILE' tee Dockerfile >/dev/null && git add Dockerfile && git commit -m 'add composer install to build'
ARG ver=7.4
FROM php:$ver-cli
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json composer.json
RUN set -ex ; \
    apt-get update ; \
    apt-get install -y git zip ; \
    composer -n validate --strict ; \
    composer -n install --no-scripts --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev

ARG ver=7.4
FROM php:$ver-apache
RUN set -ex ; \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli ; \
    a2enmod rewrite
COPY --from=0 vendor vendor
DOCKERFILE
```

Then build the container (this time with the composer.json file):

```
git archive --format tar HEAD Dockerfile composer.json | docker build --no-cache --rm --force-rm --tag my:build -
```

You'll see it run through. And given the `composer.json` file actually exists for the build context, then validates within the build container and you don't have any networking issues this should do it. You have not shared your build context properties, so this is the bare minimum for composer in docker (Dockerfile + composer.json).

Mind the PHP version in use, you find it parameterized so that the version can be controlled. Time to step away from PHP 7.4 which is going EOL soon. Docker Compose supports build parameters so you can do that in different working trees.

And here the takeaway: If you want more files from context, add them to the context and remember that when you need to copy *from* the context into the container again, there *must* be no `--from` option, that is only to copy from other containers (either intermediate stages or from the container repository). You can control all that with the Dockerfile as you had it already and additionally shown again above.